# Can I use PHP to detect if a file is already in the browser cache

Tags: php

I'm preloading 8 large background images into each page of my site by appending them to the document.body. The process is much too slow to repeat on each page, so I'm trying to figure out how to detect if the files are already in the cache before loading them again. I tried loading one image for each page, but that is also too slow.

I've read many posts on the subject of reading the browser cache and the consensus seems to be that it can't be done reliably with js or jquery.

Does anyone know if this can be done with PHP?

Here's the php code that I'm using to load the images.

```
$imgList = glob("images/*.jpg");
asort($imgList);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($imgList); $i++) {
    $imgStr .= $imgList[$i].',';
}
echo substr($imgStr, 0, strlen($imgStr) - 1);
```

Comment: No. PHP is server-side. It does not know about anything outside of that (browser in this case)

Comment: Other question is - what you gonna do **after** you check that file in cache or not?

Comment: Configure your web server to send correct cache-control headers with the images and browsers will take care of the rest automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your server should serve the images with the correct cache control headers and browsers will take care of the rest automatically.